# tabular text out of colums

Tags: tables

I would the sentence "out of column width" be inside the correspondent column. 
Any suggestions? Ideally, this should be valid for a longer sentence (after reaching the established column width, the sentence skips to the next line).

[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{\abovecaptionskip}
    \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
    \centering
    \caption{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c} }
        \toprule
        Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{c}$  & $G$\textsubscript{IC}  vs.{}    & $G$\textsubscript{IIC} vs.{}  \\
        &        &        &    & baseline     &  baseline \\
        \midrule
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{0.39} & \mr{} & \mr{Out of column width} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 0.72 &  &    \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester  & PA66 & 0.76 &  &  \\ 
        O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014}   & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 0.76 &  &   \\ 
        Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 0.76 &  &   \\ 
        Ni \cite{Ni2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 0.94 &  &   \\ 
        Nash \cite{Nash2015a,Nash2016a} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA & 1.65 &  &   \\ 
        \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{1.77} & \mr{} & \mr{} \\
        &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
        Wong \cite{Wong2017}    & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 1.92 &  &   \\ 
        Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016}  & Glass/polyester & PET & 2.03 &  &   \\ 
        Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 0.96 &  &   \\ 
        \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 0.96 & \mr{} & \mr{} \\
        &       &        &    2.80    &        &   \\
        \mr{Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PPS} & 0.68 up to 3.43 &  & \mr{} \\
        &       &        &    0.49 up to 2.40   &        &   \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your given code snippet does not compile, because we do not know the definition of command `\mr` and we do not have your used bib file nor the code you use to build the bibliography ...

With a little bit guessing I used the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================
\newcommand{\mr}{} % <==================================================

\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{\abovecaptionskip} 
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt} 
\centering 
\tiny % <===============================================================
\caption{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}p{2cm}} % <======================================
    \toprule
    Reference         & Laminate      & Veil      & $\bar{c}$  & $G$\textsubscript{IC}  vs.{}    & $G$\textsubscript{IIC} vs.{}  \\
    &        &        &    & baseline     &  baseline \\
    \midrule
    \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPA} & \mr{0.39} & \mr{} & \mr{Out of column width} \\
    &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
    Barjasteh \cite{Barjasteh2017} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA12 & 0.72 &  &    \\ 
    Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester  & PA66 & 0.76 &  &  \\ 
    O'Donovan \cite{ODonovan2014}   & Glass/polyester & PA66 & 0.76 &  &   \\ 
    Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & PEEK & 0.76 &  &   \\ 
    Ni \cite{Ni2015}    & Carbon/epoxy & Aramid & 0.94 &  &   \\ 
    Nash \cite{Nash2015a,Nash2016a} & Carbon/benzoxazine & PA & 1.65 &  &   \\ 
    \mr{Kuwata \cite{Kuwata2011, Kuwata2011a}} & Carbon/epoxy & \mr{CoPE} & \mr{1.77} & \mr{} & \mr{} \\
    &   Carbon/vynil ester     &        &        &        &   \\
    Wong \cite{Wong2017}    & Carbon/epoxy & Kevlar & 1.92 &  &   \\ 
    Fitzmaurize \cite{Fitzmaurice2016}  & Glass/polyester & PET & 2.03 &  &   \\ 
    Saz-Orozco \cite{Saz-Orozco2015}    & Glass/vynil ester & PET & 0.96 &  &   \\ 
    \mr{Beylergil \cite{Beylergil2018}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PA66} & 0.96 & \mr{} & \mr{} \\
    &       &        &    2.80    &        &   \\
    \mr{Ram\'irez \cite{Ramirez2015}} & \mr{Carbon/epoxy} & \mr{PPS} & 0.68 up to 3.43 &  & \mr{} \\
    &       &        &    0.49 up to 2.40   &        &   \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Please see that I used `\tiny` to get a smaller font and used `p{2cm}` to get a line breaking in the column if needed after 2cm ...

Package `showframe` is used to visualize the typing area and margins ...